# very basic installing pip, enabling universe, installing a program.

Tags: software-installation

I'm using Ubuntu on a usb (trying to create a cold wallet.dat file to store btc) and I was hoping this would be a good way for me to learn and practice using linux because I hope to transition to it someday, but I can't figure anything out.

Problem 1: `easy_install pip` gives the response `

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-6227.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

`
I then spent a good amount of time trying to figure out how to change the directory, which gives the response that I need to put it in the PYTHONPATH. SO I tried to figure out what the PYTHONPATH is, or how to change it. And I don't know what else I tried, but I still don't have pip.

Problem 2: To do what I'm doing I just decided to download the program from the internet so as to avoid pip. `electrum` gives the response

```
The program 'electrum' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install electrum
You will have to enable the component called 'universe'
```

So now I'm looking to enable `universe` I tried to do [these things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) which says there's an input/output error

Problem 3: Just installing electrum, which I think I need to solve either problem 1 or 2 to do so.

I'm very sorry that this is such an idiotic, stupidly simple problem I'm facing and that I should have been able to figure it out hours ago, but I'm here asking for help as a last resort. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have internet connection and [live USB persistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) to do what you are trying to do.

**Problem 1**

You should use `sudo` to run the command. So run `sudo easy_install pip`.

You can also install pip directly from Ubuntu repository without using easy_install:

> `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

**Problem 2**

Type `software sources` in Dash and open it. Tick the 'community maintained open source software (Universe)' option. Click close and choose reload from the next screen. See Ashu's (or the one above Ashu's) answer in the post [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I realized this morning that I need to re-do everything to get persistence, which has been a complete train wreck. I don't know why it just doesn't work, and I've been trying so so so many different approaches. : ( But thank you for your response and hopefully I'll get back to this point to use your suggestions.

Comment: @mcftdhorappusswrtvo did you get back to trying this point yet?! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, open software center, click edit, select software sources and enable the universe repository from there.

Next, open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install electrum python-pip
```

This will install electrum and python-pip.

If you simply want to install electrum, execute the following commands instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install electrum
```